# Proof that such a Turing machine cannot be constructed...

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, turing-machines

Prove there can be no Turing machine $M^*$ that takes input $n$ and:

i. halts printing 1 if $M_n$ halts on input 1

ii. halts printing 0 if $M_n$ doesn't halt on input 1

Intuitively I can see why such a machine can't be constructed, because in case ii. if the $M_n$ doesn't halt on input 1, we cannot determine whether it will ever halt or loop forever. However, I struggle with the construction of a formal/rigorous proof. I know problems of this nature generally work along the lines of: assume a machine can be constructed and show how it leads to a solution to the halting problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such a machine existed, where would it be on the list?

Comment: What do you mean "the list?"

Comment: @user1038665: I think Cheyne is asking what would be the value of M* applied to Mn=M*.

Comment: So we would have (for i.) $M^*$ halt printing 1 if $M^*$ halts on input 1, which I guess is self-looping, right?

Comment: This hint is a bit oversimplified.  $M^*$ halts on input $1$ iff $M_1$ halts on input $1$.  This does not lead to a contradiction.

Comment: So where do we arrive at a contradiction?

Comment: I think I see why: ii. halts printing 0 if $M*$ doesn't halt on input 1. So we have a machine that halts when it does not halt (i.e. contradiction).

Comment: Any thoughts on my conclusion here?